# Does Laptop power supply matter?

Tags: laptop, power, voltage, charger

I have a power supply which is 19.5V and 6.15A.
My friends power supply or laptop probably broke and his power supply has a 19V and 6.32A.
His charger comes with an adapter which fits my plug perfectly, would it hurt if we tested my charger on his laptop?

Comment: Other than checking polarity of the plug, It should work fine, I have done this many times, if voltage is within 1~2 volts and amperage is same or higher you are ok.

Answer (score 2):

No, that's well within the tolerances of both supply and laptop, you shouldn't have any problems assuming both have the same pin configuration, almost certainly centre-pin positive.

[image]

Be aware though that many laptops feature "intelligent" charging which attempts to ensure that an approved supply is being used by interrogating a chip inside the charger. In this case you may be presented with a "this accessory is not supported/may not work" or it may refuse to charge at all.